# Cypher loop over results

Tags: java, neo4j

I have companies that have logged in and created a relations of debt to other companies .
I want to make a query to ask who has created relations (get the first nodes in a relation)

I do it like this

```
ExecutionEngine engine = new ExecutionEngine(graphDB);
ExecutionResult result = engine.execute( "start n=node(*) match n-[r]->()  return distinct n.name");
```

When I do

```
out.println("Companies that have entered data "+result.toString());
```

I get what I wanted, but now I need to display it in the right way for my servlet. I currently do it like this

```
Iterator<Node> list_companies = result.columnAs("n.name");
while(list_companies.hasNext()){
    Node compan = list_companies.next();
    out.println(compan.getId()+" "+compan.getProperty("name"));
}
```

And I get no results. My nodes have properties name, tax number and email.
I do not think that the right way to do it is to parse

```
result.toString()
```

by removing " | +---||"...

Comment: Make sure to don't do the `out.println("Companies that have entered data "+result.toString()); ` before you iterate, otherwise you will eat up the lazy data stream and there will be no data left.

Comment: I commented it out , nothing displays...It is maybe about the way a loop through the result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are returning n.name then you'll have a property returned and not a Node:

```
Iterator<Node> list_companies = result.columnAs("n.name");
```

should most likely be:

```
Iterator<String> list_companies = result.columnAs("n.name");
while(list_companies.hasNext()){
    String compan = list_companies.next();
    out.println(compan);
}
```

If you want the id and the name properties then you could return distinct n and then it would be a Node iterator as in your example.